# SharePoint 2013 sourcedoc

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, embed, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to embed a OneNote document in a page in SharePoint 2013. I know the code needed to embed an iframe (because SharePoint gives it to you with documents like Word), but the piece I'm missing is the sourcedoc code. I haven't found a way to get this yet--it's not in the properties. Does anyone have an idea of where this number can be found? It looks something like sourcedoc={9c9e3914-cf3a-4c7e-aed9-a3904c7c2291}. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ETag field of the document. It refers to particular document and it's version if versioning enabled.